# GMSMarker маркеры не добавляются на карту Google

Tags: google-maps, xcode, google-maps-api, ios

Создаю карту таким способом:

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:self.camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
self.smallMap=mapView_;
```

Затем пытаюсь добавить маркеры на карту:

```
 -(void)addAnnotation:(NSString*)latitudeString and:(NSString*)longitudeString withName:(NSString *)name
{
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latitudeString doubleValue], [longitudeString doubleValue]);
    marker.title = name;
    marker.map = self.smallMap;

}
```

Но на карте их нет. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

У вас, похоже, все правильно. Нужно бряку влепить в ваш

```
-(void)addAnnotation:(NSString*)latitudeString and:(NSString*)longitudeString withName:(NSString *)name
```

и глянуть параметры. И еще проверить метод, где у вас вызывается первый блок вашего кода.

Я создаю так:

```
@interface MapDetailViewController ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate>{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoord;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D placeCoord;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) GMSMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GMSMarker *placeMarker;

- (void)startUpdatingCurrentLocation;
@end
```

Это в (void)loadView:

```
placeCoord = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){.latitude = 49.587657, .longitude = 36.463008}; //координаты от фонаря вставил
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:placeCoord.latitude
                                                        longitude:placeCoord.longitude
                                                             zoom:10];
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
_mapView.delegate = self;
_mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
_mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
self.view = _mapView;
```

А это в (void)viewWillAppear:

```
// Create a placeMarker.
self.placeMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
self.placeMarker.position = placeCoord;;
self.placeMarker.title = @"Title";
self.placeMarker.snippet = @"Place location";
self.placeMarker.map = _mapView;
[self updateDataRouteWithCurentLocation:startCoord];
```

У меня так работает.

И это на всяк случай для добавления маршрута на карту:

```
-(void)addDirections:(NSDictionary *)json{
    if ([json[@"routes"] count] > 0) {
        NSDictionary *routes = json[@"routes"][0];
        NSDictionary *route = routes[@"overview_polyline"];
        NSString *overview_route = route[@"points"];
        GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:overview_route];
        GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
        polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0;
        polyline.map = self.mapView;
    }
}
```

Comment: смотрите, я карту гугл не помещяю в self.view, а помещаю в отдельную небольшую вьюшку self.smallMap. Может, проблема как-то с этим связана?

Answer (score 0):

Все проще, при создании карты в другой вьюхе не надо заново ее инициализировать:

```
_smallMap = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.smallMap.bounds camera:camera];
```

Также не надо использовать дефолтный `mapView_`.

Достаточно лишь задать класс GMSMapView для вьюги и создать @property для него.

Comment: не за что         .